# How to make a d3 sankey link flow out the bottom of the diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

With a d3.js sankey diagram, how can I make a link flow out of a node and off the diagram towards either the bottom or top? This necessitates a 90deg turn in the link and for it to not end at a node (or at least not one in the diagram) and symbolizes a flow going out of the modeled system.

I want it to look something like the 'Finished Petroleum Products' link in this [diagram](http://www.knowtheflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/oil-flow-daily-lives.jpg).

Specifically I'm using this [boilerplate](http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779), but a more generic answer is fine I'm stuck on which methods I can use to make this happen but once I know what to use and how to use them I can implement it.

Update: Basically, what I'm wondering is how to re-write one of the d3 functions (which?) to make a link terminate with a horizontal line (ie flush with the SVG ceiling or floor) instead of a vertical line (ie another node's side face).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a function I used to create a link path which leaves a node on its right, goes horizontally briefly, bends upwards with a quarter-circle and exits the ceiling of the diagram. I was naive in that the solution had nothing to do with re-writing a D3 function..it just took learning how to use the [SVG path language](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js).

```
  function drawPathLeavingDiagram(link) {
     var x0 = link.source.x + link.source.width,
         x1 = x0 + link.source.width / 4,
         x2 = x1 + link.source.width / 2,
         y0 = link.source.y + link.sourceY + link.thickness / 2,
         y1 = y0 - link.source.width / 2,
         rx = link.source.width / 2,
         ry = link.source.width / 2;
     return "M" + x0 + "," + y0 + "L" + x1 + "," + y0 + 
            "A" + rx + "," + ry + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + "," + 0 + "," + x2 + "," + y1 + 
            "V" + 0;
  }
```

Comment: How did you implement this?  Did you put this in the Sankey.js function or somewhere after the diagram is laid out? Just wondering how this is used to create the exit paths.